# C# code to find most current file and type

Tags: c#, file

Sorry folks...first post here.  Just getting the hang of this site.  Thanks for the help thus far.  I am now past the first error due to the "" being there.  Now, the program runs but it does not write to the App.config file to update the file name.

```
    private static bool FindAndNoteMostRecentMsl() 
    {
        // Get files from directory
        Console.WriteLine("Finding log file");
        string logsFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFilePath"];
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(logsFilePath);

        FileInfo mostRecentMslFile = (from file in directory.GetFiles()
                                      where file.Extension.ToLower() == "msl"
                                      orderby file.CreationTime descending
                                      select file).FirstOrDefault();

        // 1) update name of most recent MSL in config
        UpdateAppSettingValue("CurrentMslFileName", "mostRecentMslFile.Name");

        // If nothing found, exits the program
        if (mostRecentMslFile == null)
            Console.WriteLine("...File not found...");
            return false;

        // If most recent MSL matches value in App.config, does nothing
        string mslFileNameInConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CurrentMslFileName"];
        if (mslFileNameInConfig == mostRecentMslFile.Name)
            return true;

        // 2) reset counter in config
        UpdateAppSettingValue("CurrentErrorCounter", "0");

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why not copy and paste the error you are seeing, and tell us exactly which line it is happening on. It's a skill you'll have to learn yourself to fix these kinds of problems, and if you need help, you'll need to provide more precise error info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a typo maybe, you want to use the varaible `logsFilePath` not `"logsFilePath"`:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("logsFilePath");

-->

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(logsFilePath);
```

Comment: you realize you can edit the question right?